# UIDocument subclass throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS in unit tests

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

I am working with a UIDocument-based app. The problem is in the unit tests - most of the unit tests are set up to initially load a document into memory using:

```
UIDocument* document = [[UIDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"document.txt"]];
[document readFromURL:document.fileURL error:nil];
```

The problem I'm getting is that upon trying to send the readFromURL message to `document`, the debugger throws an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" and halts the unit tests. I am at my wits' end - I tried using the `openWithCompletionHandler` but that didn't provide any help. Anyone have any ideas as to how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you aren't passing in a proper file URL

The simplest way to do this is to add your test document into the unit testing bundle and retrieve it from there.

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSURL *documentURL = [bundle URLForResource:@"document" ofType:@"txt"];
```

you need to do it this way because unit tests don't use the main application bundle.